# Scala - Unable to figure out this Expression evaluation

Tags: scala

I am Scala beginner. I could not understand the Scala expression below :

```
x = if(true) x+1 else x-1
```

Well the initial value of x is 3, after executing the above expression it becomes 4.

I am not able to understand `if(true)`, what is it actually evalutating ?

Comment: In a sense, that statement doesn't "evaluate" anything.  `if (<condition>)` evaluates whether the <condition> is true or false.  `true` is always true so `if (true)` will never branch to the `else` statement.

Comment: It's a very odd statement. First off, it doesn't do anything useful; `true` is always true. Second, this reassigns `x` meaning `x` must be a `var`, which is sometimes ok, but quite rarely so. Where did you come across this statement?

Comment: @Martijn .. Thank you.. one of the tutorials :) the tutor did not explain this expression completely (maybe I wasn't able to grasp it in the right way)

Comment: Thank you Martijn and jwvh :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`if(true) x else y` will always execute the if branch because the condition is `true`. Thus, the result of your if expression will be always `x + 1`.

Comment: Hi Till , thank you for your reply, how this become True ? , is it checking is 'x' is already defined or is there any value present in 'x'

Comment: @user3211648, the condition which is evaluated for the if branch is the expression within the parentheses which is the boolean literal `true`. The boolean literal `true` is evaluated as true and thus the if branch is executed. This has nothing to do with the value of `x`.

Comment: Thank you Till .. that's  helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

With a nod to @TillRohrmann, for us Scala newbies, things are sometimes not as clear as they are to seasoned programmers. Here is my attempt at detail, not just for you but for others who might have a similar question in future.

```
x = if (true) x+1 else x-1
```

Think of your expression as

```
x = function_if ( argument=true ) {
        if (argument = true ){
            return x+1
        }else{
            return x-1
        }
    }
```

Since the argument is always `true`, the answer is always `x+1`.
Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation :)